# How to get tight tire on rim of a road bike

Tags: tire, road

I have been having trouble getting a fresh tire onto a road bike wheel. The tire is "continental Grand Sport race 23mm" and the bike is a scattante road bike. I have looked at tips and watched videos including this one

but the part I am having trouble with (currently) is the first bead, which everything seems to skip over, saying it is "easy."  I have tried it both with inflating the tube somewhat and trying to put on the tire with the tube already in it, like in the above video, and just the tire itself. I make less progress with the tube.
I can get the tire about 6/8 or 7/8 of the way around and no amount of pushing, pulling, and general finger destroying will get it on. 
Is there anything I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: Some tires (and tire+rim combinations) are just hard (especially narrower tires+rims), but the first bead you can wiggle on, since you have some manuverability from the other bead not being on.

Comment: Leave the tube out for the first bead. I normally find the problem is that the whole tyre falls off the rim rather than it being too tight. Are you absolutely certain that you have the right size tyre?

Comment: @malutz1, you can try a drop of dish washing liquid as a bead lube, it did help me somewhat to fit extremely tight road tires.

Comment: Rare but I have had to use a tire lever to get the first bead on.

Comment: @Klaster_1: if you use dish washing liquid, be sure to clean the rim properly afterwards to remove any soapy substance from the braking surface!

Comment: @Carel, that's a good point, I didn't think that OP might have rim brakes.

Comment: Road bikes usually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with the second bead, push the part of bead that is already on the rim to the deepest part in the middle of the rim. Leave the tube completely out, you can put it on after the first bead has been completed.

Comment: Yes, with some wheel/tire combos you must make sure the bead of the tire falls into the deep part of the rim in the middle, while trying to monkey the last several inches on.  This can be necessary for both the first and second bead (and is, alas, much more difficult for the second).  And leave the tube out until you have the first bead mounted.